# Keras load_model error when using loop and Lambda layer in model definition

Tags: tensorflow, keras

The minimal example is presented as follows

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, Lambda, Concatenate
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.optimizers import Adam


def build_model_with_loop():
    x = Input(shape=(22,), name='inputs')
    # 2 branches
    xls = [[] for i in range(2)]
    branch = [[0,10],[10,22]]
    for _i, (b, e) in enumerate(branch):
        xls[_i] = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, b:e])(x)
    c = Concatenate()(xls)
    y = Dense(1)(c)
    model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(1E-3))
    return model

def build_model_without_loop():
    x = Input(shape=(22,), name='inputs')
    # 2 branches
    xls = [[] for i in range(2)]
    xls[0] = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 0:10])(x)
    xls[1] = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 10:22])(x)
    c = Concatenate()(xls)
    y = Dense(1)(c)
    model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(1E-3))
    return model     


model = build_model_without_loop()
model.save('model_test.h5')
model = load_model('model_test.h5')
```

The model is simple enough. The input shape is `[batch_size, 22]`, and the model will first separate the inputs into 2 branches with shape `[batch_size, 10]` and `[batch_size, 12]` respectively. Here we use `Lambda` layer in keras to do the separation. However, if we use `for` loop in the definition of model, then the saved model `model_test.h5` can not be loaded by `load_model` correctly. The error message is presented as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/junjiechen/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1659, in _create_c_op
c_op = c_api.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 24 and 22. Shapes are [24,1] and [22,1]. for 'Assign' (op: 'Assign') with input shapes: [24,1], [22,1].
ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 24 and 22. Shapes are [24,1] and [22,1]. for 'Assign' (op: 'Assign') with input shapes: [24,1], [22,1].
```

However, if we use `build_model_without_loop`, then everything goes fine. How can I fix this problem and use loop in model definition properly ?

In fact, the problem may comes from `Lambda` layer as well. If the two branches have the same dimension `[batch_size, 11]`, then no error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use `arguments` option in `Lambda` layer such that the corresponding argument can be passed correctly. In fact, the problem shown above is due to the `lambda` function of python.

```
def build_model_with_loop():
    x = Input(shape=(22,), name='inputs')
    # 2 branches
    xls = [[] for i in range(2)]
    branch = [[0,10],[10,22]]
    def get_branch(x, beg, end):
        return x[:, beg:end]
    for i, (b, e) in enumerate(branch):
        xls[i] = Lambda(get_branch, arguments={'beg':b, 'end':e})(x)
    c = Concatenate()(xls)
    y = Dense(1)(c)
    model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(1E-3))
    return model
```

Here we define `get_branch` function wrapper and pass `beg` and `end` through `arguments` option in `Lambda` layer.